# How to remove gap between first and second entry of LoF

Tags: overleaf

I am really new at latex and for some reason in my LoF the gap between the first and the second entry is bigger than the gaps between all the other entries. Does anybody know how I can change that?
[image]
I've added some example code, I hope thats correct. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[]{thesisclass}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
\clearpage


%% ==============
\chapter*{Abstract} 
\textit{some text}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\clearpage
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
%% -------------------
%% |   Directories   |
%% -------------------
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\clearpage
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}



\iflanguage{english}{
\ifthenelse{\equal{\mytype}{Seminar Thesis}}
{}
{
\listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} 
\listoftables  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables} 
\printnomenclature   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations} 
}
}


\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%% ===========================
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:Introduction}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for adding some code. Unfortunately it's not really code that people can use to help you. Code you add to a question should be self-contained and should allow people to reproduce your problem but with no extra code.

Comment: Blank lines in the TOC are usually added by \chapter using \addtocontents.  Chek the aux and toc files.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the wrong code. I checked how to provide a minimal working example, I think thats what your talking about. Will do it correctly the next time. Meanwhile I found the solution for my issue. I just added 
`\newcommand*{\noaddvspace}{\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}}` and
`\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\noaddvspace}`
This solved the issue for me, if anyobody else has the same  problem.